# issue while upload into appspot

Tags: google-app-engine

By using **dev_appserver.py --smtp_host=smtp.example.com --smtp_port=25 \
    --smtp_user=ajohnson --smtp_password=k1tt3ns myapp**  like command line argument I am able to send Email ... But after **uploading to appspot.com**, we can't able to pass arguments like above..

how can I solve my Email issue while up load in to appspot  reply me..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Google App Engine uses its own mail server for sending e-mail from live applications. Have a look at the [Google App Engine Mail API reference](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/).

Comment: By seen that code only I implemented, but there its not mentioned, with out entering  command line arguments to up load into appspot

with the above command line argument I can able to execute in my local

main thing is that we need to enter host name, user name, password we are passing through command line argument, then how can with out that we can upload ?

Comment: I'm sorry but as far as I know, you can't use a different host or user for sending mail from a live Google App Engine application. You can affect the sender field, however. See the GAE Mail API reference I linked above.

Comment: Thanks Blixt, But through code I am not mentioning any  host name, user name and Password,through command line argument only  I am passing, as per above link. then how can I solve my issue ?